# c++ post request command winsock

Tags: c++, winsock2

I **know c++ windows socket and i can connect to HTTP server.**
**why at every command sent to the server i must use "/r/n" at the end?**
**I want to fill forms (boxes) in HTTP site.**
I heard u can do this with post request, how to do that in c++ using windows sockets?
What command should i send?
What is get? post? 
I don't want to do that in lib curl and things like that.
What command i need to send?
Should i send it in one time or using send function multiply times?

Comment: Maybe you should read up about the http standard...

Comment: i read. can you give me link and answer my question

Comment: This is not something that can be explained in the format of SO answers. And by the way, yelling does not get you anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP 1.1 protocol is defined in [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). This document describes things like why lines end with "\r\n" (see section 2.2, but it basically say "because we had to make a decision, so we decided on \r\n"). Section 5 talks about requests, which is where things like POST are discussed and contains pointers to individual sections about each verb.

If you want a higher level HTTP API that is still part of Windows, you could use [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To implement things like submitting a form, you probably want to also look at the various HTML specs' topics on form submission. The HTML 4.0.1 spec talks about this in [section 17.13](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) These specs will tell you how to craft the HTTP requests that you will need to make against the server.

Implementing automated form submission via sockets alone is a large undertaking. :-)

Comment: HELP ME I READ A FEW API AND CAN UNDERSTAND THEM. BUT THERE ARE SOME API THAT I DONT UNDERSTAND THEIR BEHAVIOUr and the parameters passed to the functions what can i do? can someone tell me what to do so i understand api functions better and how to become better ? u have tutorial? what should i know before api and msdn site??